# PyQt6: Remove arrow from QToolBar action with popup menu

Tags: python, pyqt6, qmenu, qaction, qtoolbar

Currently I am working on a file explorer and ran into this problem;
the arrow and little "button" per say I have been trying to:

[image]

1. Remove the arrow entirely
2. Join the 2nd "button" with the QAction on the Toolbar
3. The QAction would act as a drop down menu

How would I go about trying this. I have attempted this so far:

1. `setStyleSheet("::menu-arrow { image: none; }")`
2. `setStyleSheet("::icon { display: none; }")`
3. `setStyleSheet("::menu-indicator { image: none; }")`

QToolBar --> QAction --> QMenu

```
def setUpMainWindow(self):
    self.main_toolbar = QToolBar()
    self.setUpToolBar()

    self.addToolBar(self.main_toolbar)
    self.addToolBarBreak()
    ...................
    ..............
    .........



def setUpToolBar(self):
    self.main_toolbar.setFixedHeight(45)
    self.main_toolbar.setMovable(False)
    self.main_toolbar.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.ContextMenuPolicy.DefaultContextMenu)
    self.main_toolbar.setIconSize(QSize(25, 25))
    self.main_toolbar.setToolButtonStyle(Qt.ToolButtonStyle.ToolButtonIconOnly)

    t_back_i = QIcon(QPixmap("icons/back.png"))
    self.t_back_act = QAction(t_back_i, "")
    self.t_back_act.setToolTip("Back")
    self.t_back_act.triggered.connect(self.directory_back_process)

    t_fwrd_i = QIcon(QPixmap("icons/forward.png"))
    self.t_frwd_act = QAction(t_fwrd_i, "")
    self.t_frwd_act.setEnabled(False)
    self.t_frwd_act.triggered.connect(self.directory_forward_process)

    t_path_output_i = QIcon(QPixmap("icons/vert-menu.png"))
    self.t_path_output_act = QAction(t_path_output_i, "")
    #self.t_path_output_act.setFixedSize(30,30)
    self.t_path_output_act.setMenu(self.window_context_menu)

    t_srch_i = QIcon(QPixmap("icons/search.png"))
    self.t_srch_act = QAction(t_srch_i, "")

    self.dirPath_h_box = QHBoxLayout()
    self.dirPath_h_box.setContentsMargins(10, 0, 10, 0)
    self.dirPath_h_box.setSpacing(5)
    self.dirPath_h_box.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignLeft)




    pathOutput_widget = QWidget()
    pathOutput_widget.setLayout(self.dirPath_h_box)
    self.pathOutput = QScrollArea()
    self.pathOutput.setFixedSize(415,30)
    self.pathOutput.setObjectName("tbFrame")

    self.pathOutput.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
    self.pathOutput.horizontalScrollBar().setStyleSheet("QScrollBar {height:0px}")
    self.pathOutput.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    self.pathOutput.setWidgetResizable(True)
    self.pathOutput.setWidget(pathOutput_widget)



    spacer_1 = QWidget()
    spacer_1.setFixedWidth(5)
    spacer_2 = QWidget()
    spacer_2.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)
    spacer_3 = QWidget()
    spacer_3.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)

    self.main_toolbar.addWidget(spacer_1)
    self.main_toolbar.addAction(self.t_back_act)
    self.main_toolbar.addAction(self.t_frwd_act)
    self.main_toolbar.addWidget(spacer_2)
    self.main_toolbar.addWidget(self.pathOutput)
    self.main_toolbar.addAction(self.t_path_output_act)
    self.main_toolbar.addAction(self.t_srch_act)
    self.main_toolbar.addWidget(spacer_3)


    self.displayPath(QDir.homePath())

def setUpContextMenu(self):
    self.window_context_menu = QMenu()
    self.window_context_menu.setObjectName("idk")
    self.window_context_menu.addAction(self.copy_directory_act)
    #self.window_context_menu.addAction(self.paste_directory_act)
    self.window_context_menu.addAction(self.new_directory_act)
    self.window_context_menu.addAction(self.delete_directory_act)
    #self.window_context_menu.addAction(self.select_all_act)


 def setUpActions(self):
    self.copy_directory_act = QAction("Copy")
    self.copy_directory_act.triggered.connect(self.copy_directory)
    self.paste_directory_act = QAction("Paste")
    #self.paste_directory_act.triggered.connect(self.paste_directory)
    self.new_directory_act = QAction("New Folder")
    self.new_directory_act.triggered.connect(self.new_directory)
    self.delete_directory_act = QAction("Delete")
    self.delete_directory_act.triggered.connect(self.delete_directory)
    self.select_all_act = QAction("Select All")
    #self.select_all_act.triggered.connect(self.select_all)
```

** I understand that it says "setUpContextMenu", though not relating to the actual context menu of the QToolbar.

Comment: Sorry but your question is very confusing. First of all, what should be the behavior of the button? Does it do something when clicked, while still providing the menu? Or should the menu be always opened instantly after the button is pressed? Also, please put the code in the correct order, possibly providing a valid [mre] that includes only what's necessary to understand the question (so, for example, remove all those connections, as they are irrelevant to what you're asking).

Comment: @musicamante The entirety of def setUpMainWindow is around 750 lines of code with the project so far at 1134. This is why I have not copy/pasted all of it down

Comment: That's why I specifically asked for a MRE, not the entirety of the code (you *did* read the link above, didn't you?). We need a code that is as short as possible (*minimal*) in order to let us understand the problem (without jumping here and there) and possibly *reproduce* it on our computers. Take your time and create an example short enough that can allow us to understand and possibly *see* your issue. It normally is no more than 100-150 lines (and your case probably needs much less) and should allow anybody to just copy, paste and run it on their own without any substantial modifications.

Comment: Also, you didn't reply to any of my questions. Please answer them and provide a *valid* MRE: I've just seen your update, but, sorry, it's neither minimal nor reproducible: it has a lot of code that is completely irrelevant to what you're asking, which *could* be acceptable if it was at least reproducible (so that we could have been able to *see* the result when running it), but that's not the case. Please, take your time and do as asked; SO is not about quick answers to questions posted in a hurry (some posts get replies even **years** after being asked), it's about their *quality*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you want a toolbar button (with no extra arrows) that simply opens a menu and does nothing else. This functionality is provided by [ToolButtonPopupMode.InstantPopup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtoolbutton.html#ToolButtonPopupMode-enum) - but to activate it, you need to access the [QToolButton](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtoolbutton.html) object that is created for the action. Once you have that, you can also set a stylesheet on it to remove the menu-arrow.

Here's a basic demo that does that:

[image: screenshot]

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        toolbar = self.addToolBar('Test')
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self)
        menu.addAction('This')
        menu.addAction('That')
        menu.addAction('Thus')
        action = QtGui.QAction(self.style().standardIcon(
            QtWidgets.QStyle.StandardPixmap.SP_DirOpenIcon), 'Open', self)
        action.setMenu(menu)
        toolbar.addAction(action)
        button = toolbar.widgetForAction(action)
        button.setPopupMode(
            QtWidgets.QToolButton.ToolButtonPopupMode.InstantPopup)
        button.setStyleSheet('::menu-indicator {image: none}')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(['Test'])
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 300, 200)
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: This was correct; removed the arrow with the menu appearing upon a click event